# using median function to create a new variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr, median

I would like to use the median function in order to create a new variable.If an observation (person that has been polled) in the sample has an education level greater than the median of the sample then he will be considered having a "high_educ". If his level of education is lower than the median then he will be considered "low_educ".

There are 1247 observations (n) in my sample so I should end up with something like 623 low_educ and 624 high_educ.

In below code I didn't include the median function as I do not know how to include it. Instead, I am manually including a threshold (here: 13.5) But of course doing like this my sample population is not equally divided by 2 as it should be if I was using the median function.
For your info, "educ" values are integers and my query seems to work only when I add as.numeric before (educ) in the ifelse function.

```
educ12<-gss%>%  
  filter(year==2012, !is.na(educ), !is.na(abany))%>%  
  mutate(education = ifelse(as.numeric(educ)>=13.5, "high_educ", "low_educ"))
```

Could you please help me to understand how to use the median function in my code?

Thanks a lot

Michael

Comment: Can't you just replace `13.5` by `median(educ)` or `median(as.numeric(educ))`?  Also -- are you sure that those are not factors in your dataframe rather than actual integers? The default way that R reads csv files sometimes creates accidental factor variables

Comment: Hi John, I followed your suggestion and the query works but I do not get an equal number of observations in my 2 variables: I get 604 high_educ and 643 low_educ. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: 643 - 604 = 39 observations which equal the median

Comment: Thanks John, that makes sense. So if i change my ">=" sign to just ">" should I not get 2 equal variables? Instead, I still get the 643 & 604.

Comment: If you change to `>` the alternative becomes `<=`, i.e., the values equaling the median will always fall into one group if you use an `if` construct. There are possible alternatives (like assigning those values randomly into the groups), but you have to decide what you'd like to do.

Comment: one solution is to add a very little amount of noise to the variable, but that"s equivalent to randomly assigning some people with the median value to one group or the other. Or use the mean instead of the median!! or the trimmed mean if you are worried about some outliers

Comment: You could create a third category of `med_education` and use nested `ifelse` to implement a 3-way classification, although being equal to a specific value is a somewhat dubious class.

Comment: Thanks Roland for your reply. I will look if I can find the function that will allow me to randomly assign the values equal to the median. Thanks again

Comment: You could type `class(educ12$educ)` at the console and see what you get. Using `as.numeric()` here is a bit of a red-flag. It would be better if you could fix whatever the underlying problem is once and for all.

Comment: John,     class(educ12$educ)
[1] "integer"

Comment: John, sorry my bad. when I remove as.numeric, my query still works. Thanks for your help.